# Basic for-loop with indexing not running why?

Tags: r

I am not sure why this for-loop with index is not working correctly. I want entries in "result" to be 'yes' if b is 'negative' and timediff is >400. Result is otherwise 'no'. I have the dataset:

```
a <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C')
timediff <- c(150, 275, 500, 120, 350, 450, 150, 1050, 1000, 150, 500, 200)
b <- c('negative', 'negative', 'lost','positive','negative','lost','return','return','negative','negative','negative','lost')
df <- data.frame(a,timediff,b)
```

Desired output:

```
result <- c('no','no', NA, NA,'no',NA,NA,NA,'yes','no','yes',NA)
```

Current wrong output:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

My code:

```
i = 1
df$result <- NA
for (i in 1:length(df)) {
if (df$b[i] == 'negative') {
        if (df$timediff[i] >400) {
        df$result[i] == 'yes'            
      } else {df$result[i] == 'no'}
      }}
print(df$result)
```

*Also, I know this may not be the most efficient way to solve this problem and welcome additional solutions, but my main question is why this for-loop isn't working. Thanks!!

Comment: `df$result[i] == 'yes'` is a comparison, not an assignment. To assign a value use only one `=` or, better yet, `<-`. Also, you don't need the initial `i = 1`.

Comment: And `1:length(df)` should be `1:nrow(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `for` loop corrected.

```r
result <- c('no','no', NA, NA,'no',NA,NA,NA,'yes','no','yes',NA)

df$result <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$b[i] == 'negative') {
    if (df$timediff[i] > 400) {
      df$result[i] <- 'yes'
    } else {df$result[i] <- 'no'}
  }
}
identical(result, df$result)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And here is a solution with index vectors, no loops. This type of solutions are faster.

```r
result <- c('no','no', NA, NA,'no',NA,NA,NA,'yes','no','yes',NA)

df$result <- NA
i <- df$b == 'negative'
j <- df$timediff > 400
df$result[i & j] <- 'yes'
df$result[i & !j] <- 'no'

identical(result, df$result)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you! Why nrow() instead of length()?

Comment: @pandas123 - `length(df)` will return the number of *columns* in `df`, as a `data.frame` is really just a `list` where each component is a column. `nrow(df)` on the other hand explicitly returns the number of *rows* in `df`